# R 3.6.3 faster than R 4.2.2?

Tags: r, performance

I am not sure wether this is the right place for this question, but I've upgraded my R from 3.6.3 to 4.2.2 and my experience has been that the 4.2.2 version is way slower than the older one in some cases. Is this really an issue with R 4.x compared to R 3.6.x or do I need to adjust anything on my setup?

I found this link regarding a problem similar to mine with R 4.0.2: https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/issues/412

Sample code (runs on average twice as fast on 3.6.3 than on 4.2.2)

*I know this could be a package implementation issue rather than an R version issue, but I had problems with other scripts that do not use any of the packages below*

```
library(tictoc)
library(seasonal)


times <- c()
for(j in 1:100) {
  print(j)
  tic()
  for(i in 1:20) {
    try({ final(seas(ts(1:120 +  runif(120), start = c(1990, 1), frequency = 12))) })
  }
  elapsed <- toc()
  times <- c(elapsed, unname(elapsed$toc - elapsed$tic))
}
```

Other informations:

→ Everything ran on the same machine

Session Info for 3.6.3

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] seasonal_1.9.0 tictoc_1.0    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] x13binary_1.1.39-2 compiler_3.6.3     tools_3.6.3
```

Session Info for 4.2.2

```
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8    LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] seasonal_1.9.0 tictoc_1.1    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_2.1-0   scales_1.2.1       x13binary_1.1.57-3 compiler_4.2.2     R6_2.5.1           cli_3.6.0          tools_4.2.2        rstudioapi_0.14   
 [9] lifecycle_1.0.3    munsell_0.5.0      rlang_1.0.6
```

Comment: What OS is this running on? Are both of these on the exact same machine? What versions of these packages are you running? Did you install R from CRAN or did you compile yourself? What matrix libraries are being used in each R version?

Comment: we cant help without proper debugging details